# Application of BFS or DFS

Tags: java, search

I need help in solving this problem, I tried using a 2D array and then finding the least number of swaps. Not sure exactly how to go about this problem. Whether to use BFS or DFS?

You are given two four digits numbers. The first number is the initial number, and the second one is the target number. Write a java program to transform the initial number into the target number using the fewest possible operations. The available operations are as follows:
Add 1 to one of the four digits. Adding 1 to a 9 results in 0.
Subtract 1 from one of the four digits. Subtracting 1 from 0 results in 9.
Swap two adjacent digits

eg 1:
initial no :1111

final no : 9999

min no of operations :8

eg 2:
initial no :1234

final no : 2144

min no of operations :2

Comment: On eg 2 you mean min no of operations is 2, right?

Comment: ya min no of operations should be 2, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

BFS.

When DFS finds first solution it is usually not one found in the smallest possible number of moves. It can also explore long, pointless paths when solution is close (it can get stuck in infinite loop if you don't remember visited nodes). These problems could be solved by iterative deepening DFS, which might be desirable if there are memory constraints, but BFS is simpler for such small search space.

Comment: But how exactly would I go about a BFS to find the minimum number of operations for this problem?

Comment: @user_J, use map/array to map states (numbers) to distance (where known) and build a queue of states. Check some BFS examples.

Answer (score 0):

You should use BFS algorithm, because it will give you the shortest possible way to transform the first number to the targeted one. DFS only explore the paths, and not by shortest way. In some cases, DFS might find the solutions faster than BFS, but there is no algorithmic guarantee for that.